# Regex to strip specific characters when a particular patten exists

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a set a ids that I need to match. I would really love to understand how to build a Regex like this so an explanation would be highly appreciated

- IT-12
- AXT 6000, GQ-84732
- DG-1000K
- kj249
- p-238
- wf 1234

I'd like to find this pattern 2-5 alpha characters + ( a hyphen | a space) + a series of numbers + and optional 1-2 characters immediately after the number (no space).

Each time that pattern is found in a string, I would like to switch the whole thing to lowercase and strip and spaces or hyphens out. So, the desired output for the above option would be:

- it12
- axt6000, gq84732
- dg1000k
- kj249
- p238
- wf1234

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/: good luck!

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or C#?  They are very different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following RegEx: `/^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(-| )\d+[^ ]{0,2}$/`

**RegEx breakdown:**

- `^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}` checks for a string that starts with with 2-5 alpha characters,
- `(-| )` checks for hyphen or space in the middle
- `\d+` checks for any number of digits
- `[^ ]{0,2}$` checks for between 0 and 2 of any characters but space at the end of the string

**JavaScript breakdown:**

- `s.replace(/-| /g, '')` is to replace all hyphens and spaces with an empty string, which effectively removes all hyphens and spaces
- `toLowerCase()` makes the string lowercase

**Example:**

```js
const arr = ['IT-12','AXT 6000, GQ-84732', 'DG-1000K', 'kj249', 'p-238', 'wf 1234']

for(const s of arr){
  if(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(-| )\d+[^ ]{0,2}$/g.test(s)) console.log(s.replace(/-| /g, '').toLowerCase())
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The explanation is excellent. I had one question on this: I wanted to have the ability to catch an instance of this pattern in a string (please see the 2nd test option a string of 'AXT 6000, GQ-84732' - I was hoping to catch both instances of the pattern. How would that change the regex?

Comment: AXT 6000, GQ-84732 is comma going to be a separator?  If all characters except space can be an optional ending, then comma will be part of the pattern. Also if there is space in between patterns, do you need to remove that space? Or maybe ,with a space will be a separator? Also I updated the answer, you will need to add a $ in the end of the pattern, so the test function will look for a full match

Comment: If you know what's the separator, you can use split function to split strings by separator, then check if each string match the pattern.